# Hibernate entity classes getters returning null after setting value

Tags: java, hibernate, hashmap, dropwizard

I have a hibernate entity class

```
public class MyComplexClass implements  Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    Long id;

    String name;
    int number;
    @ElementCollection
    Map<String,String> myMap;

    @ManyToOne
    Simple simple;

    public MyComplexClass(String name, int number, Map<String,String> myMap) {
        this.name = name;
        this.port = number;
        this.myMap = myMap;
    }

    public MyComplexClass() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;

    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setNumber(int number) {
        this.port = number;
    }

    public int getPort() {
        return port;
    }

    public void setMyMap(Map<String,String> myMap) {
        this.myMap = myMap;
    }

    public Map<String,String> getMyMap() {
        return this.myMap;
    }


    public Simple getSimple() {
        return this.simple;
    }
```

And in the class simple I have a mapping of the form

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "Simple")


    public class Simple  implements Comparable<Simple>, Serializable {
    @JsonProperty
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="simple",fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    List<MyComplexClass> myComplexClass;

    public void setMyComplexClass(List<MyComplexClass> myComplexClass) {
        this.myComplexClass = myComplexClass;
    }

    public List<MyComplexClass> getMyComplexClass() {
        return this.myComplexClass;
    }
```

Somewhere in the system I set the values as

```
Map<String, String> myMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
myMap.put("value","value");
MyComplexClass myComplexClass = new MyComplexclass("a", 123, myMap)
List<MyComplexClass> myComplexClassList = new ArrayList<MyComplexClass>();
myComplexClassList.add(myComplexClassList)
simple.setMyComplexClass(myComplexClassList);
// save to the database
dao.save(simple);
```

But when I get the value as

```
Simple simple = dao.getSimple(simple.id);
`simple.getMyComplexClass.get(0).getMyMap.get("value")`
```

. It returns a null pointer . When I debug I see that the `simple.getMyComplexClass()` is null itself

Why isn't it returning the values set? Is it related to the database or in memory cache?

In the database I do see a null in the foreign key column of the MyComplex class table, is this the reason?

Comment: You must Show us more code. For instance the getter and the setter

Comment: added getters and setters

Comment: and `simple.setMyComplexClass`?

Comment: done, added the necessary getters

Comment: I Need the Information for class simple not the getter and setter in the complex class. or better the whole simple class

Comment: I've added the Simple  class infrmation

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146178/discussion-between-user-mda-and-jens).

Comment: `()` is missing after `simple.getMyComplexClass.get(0).getMyMap`